# IPhone UIImagepicker with camera showing camera roll thumbnail like default camera app?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, camera

im working in iphone's camera app, using UIImagePicker to launch the camera.
Everything goes well, just a need to use the default controls showed in the camera app in iphone(little thumbnail from the last pic in camera roll and take photo buttons) and its animation(take and send the picture to the left bottom thumbnail), not default in UIImagePicker (cancel and take photo buttons).
How i can do that?
thankz :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. What you should do is present a `UIActionSheet` and ask if the user wants to get a photo from the Camera or their Photo Albums.

Comment: Ok, thankz for the info :( Then a want to show a overlayview and hide it when preview shows up. there is a delegate that catches this event maybe "willShowPreview" to hide de overlay in this moment. Thankz again

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as correct by clicking the √ next to its left.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the cameraOverlayView property or create your own custom controls duplicating the default controls (hiding the default controls with showsCameraControls = NO).