# Enable camera roll thumbnail in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

Is there a way to display the camera roll thumbnail (marked in red below) inside a UIImagePickerController?
The right image shows what a default UIImagePickerController looks like with a camera source.

[image]
[image]

This is how I present the camera:

```
func openCamera() {
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)) {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        picker!.showsCameraControls = true
        picker!.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front
        self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        NSLog("No camera")
        openGallary()
    }
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722855/iphone-uiimagepicker-with-camera-showing-camera-roll-thumbnail-like-default-came) claims that it was not possible in 2010, but I'm hoping for new times.

Comment: It was possible back then and is still possible. You can either add it as an overlay using `setCameraOverlayView:` or even add it as a basic subview to your image picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [DBCamera](https://github.com/danielebogo/DBCamera), which lets you customize the entire camera view pretty easily.

I do believe that Lyndsey Scott is right though, it can be done by just adding a custom subview to the default camera view.